# android: play audio on a button click inside a listview row

Tags: android, listview, audio, onclick, media-player

i have some audio files (m4a/mp3) in `res/raw` folder. and my activity has a listview which inflates such that each list item has a textview, an imageview and a button. i want an audio file to play upon clicking this button. How do i achieve this? i tried `MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example);` but this line of code shows an error since its in the  ListAdapter class and not the Activity class. Any help would be appreciated, any hint on how to do it and i can do the coding.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the `Context` in several ways.

You can get it from the current view in the `getView()` method of the adapter:

```
view.getContext();
```

Or you can pass the context to the adapter's constructor, remembering that a good practice involves using a `WeakReference`, so that you do not generate leaks.

Once you do have the `Context`, the code you are using just works:

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.example);
player.prepare();
```

If you are using a WeakReference, your code will be:

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(mContext.get(), R.raw.example);
player.prepare();
```

Comment: a follow-up question- look at "R.raw.example". suppose i have a database with a list of NAMES of the audio files: aud1_1, aud2_1, aud2_2, aud2_3 etc. i can extract the respective filename but how to assign it in place of "R.raw.filename"?? its not a string value so i cannot use a variable...how do i do it?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way of accessing the `raw` folder just like any other folder in the file system, since it is bundled inside the APK and therefore handled in a special way. You need to map the names of your database to the actual raw files.

Comment: thanks... i found a workaround: mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, context.getResources().getIdentifier(mylistItems.get(position).getAudio(), "raw",context.getPackageName()));